# Android: which api to use to record all incoming and outgoing call (Since in changelogs Android blocked call recording)

Tags: android, call-recording

Is there is api where i can record all the incoming and outgoing call in android pie version . It seems nearly impossible to record a call. Please suggest what can be done in this scenario

Comment: `It seems nearly impossible to record a call` have you read the changelog for Android pie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 9 : Is call recording is allowed in Android Latest version Pie and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573634/android-9-is-call-recording-is-allowed-in-android-latest-version-pie-and-above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android disabled the api with their security update policy. Looking at the permissions list the closest you can find is the [MANAGE_OWN_CALLS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MANAGE_OWN_CALLS), meaning that the best solution for you is to implement a standalone application for calling where you should be able to interact with microphone directly.